# Calculate percentage between 2 values (Sum Case)

Tags: mysql, percentage

I want to calculate percentage of these 2 values:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN status != 'Rectified' AND status != 'Surveyed' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Attend, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN status != 'Rectified' AND status != 'Surveyed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Pend 
FROM Tickets 
WHERE Schedule Date BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-06-30'
```

Percentage of `"Attend"` & `"pend"` values separated by columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide the 2 expressions by COUNT(*):

```
SELECT 
  100.0 * SUM(status = 'Rectified' OR status = 'Surveyed') / COUNT(*) as Attend, 
  100.0 * SUM(status != 'Rectified' AND status != 'Surveyed') / COUNT(*) as Pend
FROM Tickets 
WHERE ScheduleDate BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-06-30'
```

or simpler with AVG():

```
SELECT 
  100.0 * AVG(status = 'Rectified' OR status = 'Surveyed') as Attend, 
  100.0 * AVG(status != 'Rectified' AND status != 'Surveyed') as Pend
FROM Tickets 
WHERE ScheduleDate BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-06-30'
```

I simplified the aggregated expressions because MySql evaluates the boolean expressions as 0 or 1.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Tickets
  WHERE ScheduleDate BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-06-30'
) t L' at line 6

Comment: There was an extra comma in the 2nd query. I edited

Comment: this gives me result but i want specify what is the percentage of "Attend" AND "Pend" Separate